# SWITCH macro's initValue

Tags: mps

In a template, I want to use a `$SWITCH$` macro. It requires me to specify an `<initValue>`:

[image]

What's the role of this `<initValue>`? What should/can I pass in as `<initValue>`? Note that no autocomplete suggestions appear on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Below is the Inspector of the macro:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<initValue>` is the editor of the template node which will be replaced in the process of the generation. The `SWITCH` specifies how it will be replaced.
In case of the `SWITCH` has the `<ignore switch>` as the default and there are no matches in the `SWITCH`, the template node will stay in the output model.

Modifying the template node is a bit tricky, the best option is to remove the `SWITCH` macro, modify the node (e.g. with the auto-completion) and then add the `SWITCH` macro back

Comment: Thanks. By some trial and error, first removing the SWITCH macro (and the surrounding LOOP macro) as you suggested, I managed to enter `null` as the `<initValue>`.

Answer (score 1):

All MPS macros are annotations on existing nodes so `<initValue>` is the editor of the underlying node showing through. If your switch always generates some code for each node then you don't need to care about the actual node. But if the switch has a default that says `<ignore switch>`, then the underlying node will be used as default if no cases match.

Comment: Even if I don't care about the actual node, it seems I still have to provide some. What can I type in?

Comment: That depends on where in your code the red "initValue" lives. The assumed scenario is that you first enter valid piece of code and then annotate some nodes with macros, such as $SWITCH$.